# adding second android project into first android project in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have two android studio projects..like helloworld1 and helloworld2 app..
both are separate projects..

in helloworld1 project i want to add..helloworld2 projects.. code from first project in some layout on click of button..

i want to launch helloworld2 app..how to add in android studio
can anyone help me..i went so many answers but all answers not clearly explained..
how to add it and launch it

below is some intent code i got for launchig

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, FBFeedActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(intent, MESSAGEPUBLISHED);
```

Comment: easy way will be to copy code from that project to your current project

Comment: can i copy the code but there is way to add another project code in android studio..import module like that way

Comment: yes you have to add that project as a module in your current project